# Buy >= $100 free item ABC

Tags: magento2

Is there a quick way i can use the Buy X Get Y free but with the following rules?

Buy >= $100, automatically add a specific FOC item (preconfigured) for free

Been tinkering with the cart rules but i couldn't achieve the result that i wanted to.

Comment: I found some extensions support this, you can search "free gift extension" if you need it.

Comment: Hi Bernie, welcome to Magento stack exchange. Unfortunately, the feature you are seeking is not available out of box in Magento. But there are paid extensions available for the same. So either you need to purchase an extension or develop the feature with a development team.

Comment: Thanks both for your input.